# Failed to launch the browser when GoogleDriveApplication is hosted in IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client, google-apis-explorer

I'm working with Google Drive API v3 in local it's working for creating token.json when i host to IIS server getting error :

- Access is denied

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

`Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied`

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]
```

System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +604
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +60
   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.d__14.MoveNext() +261

[NotSupportedException: Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A61855%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive" for authorization. See inner exception for details.]
   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.d__14.MoveNext() +1011
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.d__8.MoveNext() +716
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.d__4.MoveNext() +568
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.d__1.MoveNext() +435

[AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) +4757412
   TestGoogleDrive.Controllers.HomeController.Testcode() in C:\Users\xxxxxxx\source\repos\GoogleDriveTestApplication\TestGoogleDrive\Controllers\HomeController.cs:42
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +87
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +77
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__11_0() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +387
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +602
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +128

This is My google App details:

`{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "redirect_uris": [
      "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
      "http://localhost"
    ]
  }
}`

This is my Code:

```
string[] Scope = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
string ApplicationName = "testApplication";
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/credentials.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    string credPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/token.json");
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        Scope,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
    // Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
}
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });
```

Comment: Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:
 public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task UploadFileAsync()
        {
            try
            {

```
            // Create the service using the client credentials.
         var json=   HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/credentials.json");
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(json, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                    "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Audio.files"));
            };
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "YourAppName"
            });
            var uploadFilepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/filename.flac");
            var uploadStream = new System.IO.FileStream(uploadFilepath,
                                                        System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                                                        System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
            // Get the media upload request object.
            var insertRequest = service.Files.Create(
                  new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File
                  {
                      Name = "Filename.flac",
                  },
                  uploadStream,
                  "audio/flac");


            var task = insertRequest.UploadAsync();
            await task.ContinueWith(t =>
             {
                 // Remeber to clean the stream.
                 uploadStream.Dispose();
             });
            var result = task.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception EX)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: am getting same error "Failed to launch the browser"

Failed to launch the browserwhen GoogleDriveApplication is hosted in IIS Server

Comment: Have you got solution to this..I am facing the same issue..Few days back everything was working as expected.